# How to disable Universal Clipboard

Tags: macos, mac

By default, macOS adds significant latency between copying and pasting. For example Command-L-C-T-V no longer works to clone the current browser tab. Also maybe Apple sends everything on your clipboard to phone home.

I attempted to disable this using the System Preferences but there is no obvious solution there.

[image]

I do NOT want this. How do you disable it?

Comment: Sends to Apple? Everywhere I searched says that it's limited to the LAN only.

Comment: Documentation is spotty but AppleInsider and other places are talking about "uploads to iCloud". Perhaps those were misinformed.

Comment: This is the most frustrating new "feature" especially when you're doing dev work!

Comment: @FullDecent: The iCloud account is only used for verifying that both devices belong to the same person. http://arstechnica.com/apple/2016/09/ios-10-reviewed-theres-no-reason-not-to-update/9/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[Universal Clipboard](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25168) is a part of the Continuity suite of features, specifically a sub-feature of Handoff. The only way to disable it is to disable Handoff entirely.

Mac: Go to System Preferences > General > uncheck Allow Handoff

iPhone: Go to Settings > General > Handoff > uncheck Handoff

Data does not travel to Apple's servers or even over the internet. Devices advertise availability to each other via Bluetooth and data is transmitted over Wi-Fi, but only on the local network.

Comment: Well that's annoying. The pasteboard is causing lags while typing on iOS while simultaneously doing dev work on the computer.......

Comment: Who the hell came up with this? This is not even remotely secure. I didn't even know it was enabled until today.

Comment: Merely doing this is not enough. You need a powerful application firewall like [LuLu](https://github.com/objective-see/LuLu) to block the process EVEN if you have "Handoff" turned off in macOS like I already did: https://i.imgur.com/33omphz.png